# Copy-paste special VBA does not work, why?

Tags: excel

I have the following code:

```
Sheets("BG bridge").Select
Windows("F.xlsx").Activate
Range("A1:F88").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.Replace What:="  ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
Sheets("Input").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=174
Range("N196").Select
```

and I am getting error on the part

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

Basically, my macro stops there and I am not able to find out, what is wrong with this part of the code. Macro should select data on a given sheet but it fails with this selection.

Can someone help?

Comment: What is the error message, and what had you copied?

Comment: You have to cut or copy something before you can paste.  It looks like you recorded this macro but hit record after you copied your values.